# Having trouble understanding private files in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, files

I'm trying to set up private files on Drupal 7 using Organic Groups. So far, I have

**(1)** one group type that although I appear to have set it up as such

> [image]

**(2)** have private files set up in as below. (The webroot is /var/www/html.)

> [image]

**(3)** Ensured the link on the OG's page is `/system/files/test.example.doc`,

> [image]

(4) I inspected the database entry and this appears to be good.

```
MariaDB [s7data]> select * from file_managed \G

*************************** XXX. row ***************************
      fid: 357
      uid: 103
 filename: test.pwww_.doc
      uri: private://test.pwww_.doc
 filemime: application/msword
 filesize: 9
   status: 1
timestamp: 1460390385
     uuid: 3a9877fc-77b2-47bc-8d4f-e8bc349f4c74
```

I am still able, using this link path do download that doc in a new browser without being logged in. In effect, this file is not private and does *not* require an authenticated session to download.

**Question:** Did I miss something? How does one set up private files correctly on Drupal 7?

Comment: Your tmp directory should not be inside your private files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever possible it's recommended that you choose a directory located
>   outside of your Drupal root folder (or actually outside your web
>   root), which may be tricky if you are on a shared host. If you do have
>   access though, you can choose a private directory which will be on the
>   same level as your web root directory (often called public_html or www
>   or similar).

From [Working with files in Drupal 7 and Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/file).

The best practice is to place your private files outside of your webroot, so they should not be inside `/var/www` as that would make them accessible over the web. Place them in `/var/somefolder` instead, make sure your webserver has read write access to that folder. After that you should only be able to access them via `/system/files/test.example.doc` and it should not work for anonymous users.

UPDATE:

Above is based on the assumption you were accessing the file via `example.com/drupal-private-file-system/test.example.doc`. this can be prevented by using the linked best practise guide.

If an anonymous user can access your files with on url like `example.com/system/files/test.example.doc` you have a problem with your permissions and anonymous users are given the permission to download private files.

Comment: Which permission is associated with private files? That is something else that I looked for.

Comment: Depends, are you using [File Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity)?

Comment: Oh, apparently there is no such permission in vanilla Drupal... :s. That is strange because access should have been restricted then.

Comment: Is the file attached to a publicly visible entity? For instance if you attach a private file to a node and the anonymous user has `View published content` permissions (which is default) I believe the file also showed up. You might need to make sure the parent entity where the file is attached to is blocked to anonymous users by permissions. See: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/file#content-accessing-private-files

Comment: The idea is that files aren't private until you explicitly make them private - it's a bit counter-intuitive to start with. See [hook_file_download](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7) for more details